# How to use std::istream correctly

Tags: c++, istream

I want to do the following:

```
// I want 'is' to be either opened file or stringstream ...
void ParseTokens(const std::istream &is, std::vector<TokenClass> &vToks)
{
    char ch;
    ...
    is >> ch;
    ...
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator>>’ in ‘is >> ch’
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

[edit]
Just a caveat: `operator>>` gives *formatted* output - it loses white-space characters (tabs, newlines, etc). To access all the characters, you need to use `get()`.

Comment: Input operations modify the stream. You can't make it `const`.

Comment: @chris: okay - that fixed it - put your comment as answer so I can accept it, thx (the error-message is not helpful in this case :( )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `is >> ch;` extracts characters from `is`, it modifies the stream. Therefore, it can't be `const` in the function signature, which can cause seemingly irrelevant errors because there's no exact match. Change the function to take a `std::istream &`.

Comment: I suppose it's because the stream needs to increment some kind of 'next'-pointer

Comment: Well, when you think about it, with `cin >> i`, the input buffer starts with, say, `576\n`, and contains `\n` after. It has to modify it in order to do that.

Comment: @chris Technically, the input buffer is in the streambuf, not the stream itself.  This indirection could allow most of the operations on a const `istream` (the exception being setting errors like end of file).  However, the data stream is "logically" part of the `istream`, so logical const says that anything which modifies it, or your position in it, should not be const.